# Duplicate, Google chose different canonical than user

Tags: duplicate-content, google-selected-canonical

running a small ecommerce site and all of my final product pages have the
"Duplicate, Google chose different canonical than user" issue(About 5000 pages).
And Google only indexes 1 single final product page(Out of the 5000 pages).
Lets say that 1 final product page it indexes is:
Sony Monitor XXXXX(Part Number) and a small description and a small image.

What I also tried is, I removed that page, and made sure Google can't find that page anymore with a 404 and what happened Google just picked 1 other page out of the 5000 pages and indexed that
That is now lets say:
HP Laptop XXXXX(Part Number) and a small description and a small image.
And of course Google now states that all the other 5000 pages are a duplicate of this new 1 single  page indexed.

So, both lets say above 2 examples have:

1. Different Brand.
2. Different Category.
3. Different Part Number.
4. Different Small Description.
5. Different Image.
6. Different Title.
7. Different Meta Tags.

Also, they have different, correct and individual canonical tags.

Also, they have different, correct and individual product schema structured data including all attributes required to get a full green tick at the Google structured data test.

Also, they have different, correct and individual breadcrumbs schema structured data including all attributes required to get a full green tick at the Google structured data test.

So after more research, as my small descriptions of each product page is very little it could be a "thin content" problem.

So I added lots of individual product information to the description of about 38 pages, added extra images to those 38 pages. So now these pages have all of the above differences with lots of extra individual description and extra individual images which should cover the "thin content" problem.

I don't use sitemaps and of course all of the above works really well on Bing.

So I did make a sitemap of those improved 38 pages and Google correctly crawled the sitemap and the 38 pages, however even those 38 pages are now a "Duplicate, Google chose different canonical than user" of that 1 single final product page.

I'm really not sure what to do anymore after working on this for about 6 months now.  Does anyone have a solution?